# Remove Middle Part of File Name in Linux

Tags: linux, filenames, partial

I've tried lots and lots of variations using the `rename` command in the Linux command line and nothing happens when I execute these commands - no errors and no expected outcomes.  I've tried using the `find` command to find files and then rename them with no success.  I have files that look like this

```
201901.cdas1.20190101.pgrbh.grb2flxf06.grb2
201902.cdas1.20190102.pgrbh.grb2flxf06.grb2
```

and I need them to look like this for the script that is expecting a specific file name format `201901.flxf06.grb2` and `201902.flxf06.grb2`.

I need to delete the middle part of the file name with a wild card since there are dates that change in multiple files. The deleted part is this: `cdas1.pgrbh.grb2`

this is not homework and I've been searching the internet most of the day trying to use different options other than the rename option or a for loop since I get a missing } braces error.  Thank you!

Comment: `var=201901.cdas1.20190101.pgrbh.grb2flxf06.grb2;echo "${var/cdas1*.pgrbh.grb2}"` produces `201901.flxf06.grb2` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `perl` rename command:

```
rename 's/cdas1\.pgrbh\.grb2//' *.cdas1.20190101.pgrbh.grb2*.grb2
```